# Click div and go to page which another div contains

Tags: php, jquery, css, hyperlink, href

I have these two divs. I want to do:
If I click "right_absolute" or "right_relative" div, then it goes to the page from link within "marka_w_miniaturce" div.

```
<div class="right_relative">
    <div class="right_absolute"></div>
</div>  

<div class="marka_w_miniaturce">
    <a href="<?php echo get_root().'galeria.php?g='.urlencode($id_gal); ?>" title="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($marka, ENT_QUOTES); ?>">
     <?php echo htmlspecialchars($marka, ENT_QUOTES); ?>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure, that is possible. You simply register an event handler listening to the click events of those two div's. When invoked the handler fetches the target link from the anchor tag in the other div and switches the location setting to that target url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '.right_relative', function() {
  var targetLocation = $('.marka_w_miniaturce a').first().attr('href');
  window.location.href = targetLocation;
});
```

Comment: I found something funny. Every url have now the same get param like:
http://localhost/galeria.php?g=49
Everything is 49, lol.

Comment: Do I really need "first()"?